# Как вернуть при запросе ошибку

Tags: c#

Можно ли при обращение ReadProcessMemory процесса вернуть ошибку?если возможно то с примером.Цель - запретить в нужном моменте считывать память

Comment: Вы пытаетесь прочитать память другого процесса или наоборот? Опишите подробнее исходную ситуацию.

Comment: @rdorn - у меня есть нужный процесс.Нужно при обращение программ по типу Megadumper заблокировать доступ к памяти - они считывают память процесса и восстанавливают dll из byte

Comment: в теории, это задача уровня системного драйвера, вроде тех, что используют антивирусы, и не зубам C#, от слова совсем. Готовы писать на С/С++? Плюс вам придется как-то защитить вашу программу от свопа и гибернейта, при которых содержимое памяти можно прочитать тупо из соответствующих файлов, а также от BSOD с генерацией полного дампа памяти. Дальнейшие проблемы перечислять или уже хватит? Самое простое, что вы можете сделать - отслеживать список процессов и глушить свою программу, если запустилось что-то, что умеет делать дампы, но это не поможет от того кому ну очень надо, как и все остальное

Comment: Вы не можете сопротивляться программам, запущенным с администраторскими правами. Вы можете лишь выставить права на свой процесс, запрещающие чтение. Но программа с администраторскими правами может эти права отменить. Не пытайтесь победить юзера на его машине, он на своей машине царь и бог.

Comment: Если не хочется/нельзя показывать какой-то код или данные пользователю - вынесите исполнение этого кода на удаленный сервер, которым управляете только вы и общайтесь с ним по шифрованному каналу или шифрованными сообщениями. Передаете на клиент минимально необходимые данные. Тут конечно тоже проблем хватает, но решаются они несколько проще. Скорость будет пониже, да, но сначала надо понять, что нужно прятать от чужих глаз, а над чем даже думать не надо, все равно интереса не представляет.

Comment: @rdorn - весь код в dll - отдельно не передать.Dll дампится с памяти легко

Comment: правильно, дампится легко, и бороться с этим бессмысленно, кто захочет - все равно достанет. Я одного не могу понять, что в ней может быть такого ценного, что вы так боитесь дампа? В любом случае - ответ: на текущей архитектуре PC это невозможно, защитой управляет ОС, ОС можно обмануть/обойти. Если бы было иначе, то мы бы понятия не имели ни о каких вирусах и прочей пакости. На VAX, кажется, все программы были изолированы из коробки на аппаратном уровне, но VAX давно уже пал жертвой маркетологов.

Comment: @rdorn вот смотрите - в некоторых обфукскаторах есть антидамп - и он прекрасно защищает от того же megadumper - плохо в том,что обфускаторы под exe файл заточен - а у меня dll

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx вот чем они защищают, там же в самом начале статьи, есть ссылка на функцию ядра, которая эту защиту может также легко снять. Еще предложения?

Comment: @rdorn она хоть что-то защищает - смотрите любой может скачать этот megadumper и за 5 кликов получить все dll - а так хоть какая-то защита будит - не думаю как обычный пользователь - воришка будит копать дальше после нерабочего megadumper